# Ordinal regression - proportional odds assumption not met for variable in interaction

Tags: r

I try to analyze a dataset with an ordinal response (0-4) and three categorical factors. I'm interested in the interactions of all three factors as well as the main effects. I used the clm function of the package "ordinal" and checked the assumptions by using the "nominal_test" function. It revealed a significant difference for one of the predictors. And now I don't know how to proceed... I tried to put the problematic factor and all its interactions in the "nominal" argument (see code) and R gives me warnings. Nevertheless, I made several likelyhood ratio tests always comparing a model including an interaction with one missing it (ANOVA(without,with, test="Chisq")) and get some nice significant results. Still, I feel like I have no clue what I'm doing here and I don't trust the results. So my question is: Is it ok what I did? What else can I do? or is the data just 'unanalyzable'?

Here is the code for the test:

```
# this is the model
res=clm(cue~     intention:outcome:age+
                 intention:outcome+
                 intention:age+
                 outcome:age+
                 intention+outcome+age+
                 Gender,
                 data=xdata)

#proportional odds assumption
nominal_test(res)
#                      Df  logLik    AIC    LRT  Pr(>Chi)    
#<none>                   -221.50 467.00                     
#intention              3 -215.05 460.11 12.891  0.004879 ** 
#outcome                3 -219.44 468.87  4.124  0.248384    
#age                                                         
#Gender                 3 -219.50 469.00  3.994  0.262156    
#intention:outcome                                           
#intention:age                                               
#outcome:age            6 -217.14 470.28  8.716  0.190199    
#intention:outcome:age 12 -188.09 424.19 66.808 1.261e-09 ***
```

And here is an example of how I tried to solve it -> and check the 3-way-interaction of all three predictors. I did the same for the 2-way-interactions as well...

```
res=clm(cue~         outcome:age+
                     outcome+age+
                     Gender, 
                     nominal= ~ intention:age:outcome+
                                intention:age+        
                                intention:outcome+
                                intention,
                     data=xdata)
res.red=clm(cue~     outcome:age+
                     outcome+age+
                     Gender, 
                     nominal= ~ 
                                intention:age+        
                                intention:outcome+
                                intention,
                     data=xdata)
anova(res,res.red, test="Chisq")
#        no.par    AIC  logLik LR.stat df Pr(>Chisq)
#res.red     26 412.50 -180.25                      
#res         33 424.11 -179.05  2.3945  7     0.9348
```

And here is the warning that R gives me when I try to cenverge the model:

```
Warning message:
(-3) not all thresholds are increasing: fit is invalid 
In addition: Absolute convergence criterion was met, but relativecriterion was not met
```

I'm especially concerned about the sentence "Fit is not valid"... I don't know what to do with this and would be happy about any idea or hint!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to use a more general model like the partial proportional odds model? Your data only has to be nominal, not ordinal to use this model. If you find hugh differences between the log likelihoods, your assumption about ordinality is not met.

You can use vlgm() from the [VGAM](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/VGAM/VGAM.pdf) package. [Here](http://www.stat.ufl.edu/~aa/ordinal/R_examples.pdf) are a few examples.

As I don't know how your data looks like, I can't say whether it's unanalyzable, but the code would be something like this:

```
library(VGAM)
res <- vglm(cue ~ intention:outcome:age+
             intention:outcome+
             intention:age+
             outcome:age+
             intention+outcome+age+
             Gender, 
             family = cumulative(parallel = FALSE ~ intention),
             data = xdata)
summary(res)
```

I think you could use pchiq() as proposed in the example I posted above to compare both models like you did before with anova():

```
pchisq(deviance(res) - deviance(res.red),
     df = df.residual(res) - df.residual(res.red), lower.tail = FALSE)
```

Comment: Wow that was quick! Thank you! The code you suggested did not work but I added something to the family argument which I think defines the predictor for which the assumptions are not met (intention) and then it works!   `res <- vglm(cue ~ intention:outcome:age+
             intention:outcome+
             intention:age+
             outcome:age+
             intention+outcome+age+
             Gender, 
             family =cumulative(parallel=FALSE~intention), 
             data = xdata)`

Comment: Oh it doesn't allow ANOVA for likelihood ratio tests... So how do I get the effects of the interactions and a full/null model comparison?

Comment: @PatriciaG. If you use summary() you should get p values for every scenario. What else do you need?

Comment: Yes in the summary are p-values for specific combinations of my factors (the interactions). But I need p-values for the 'overall' effect of the interactions. Usually I get them by comparing the original model with a second (reduced) model without the interaction using the function `anova(original model, reduced model, test="Chisq")` For vglm s the `anova` function is not (yet) available...

Comment: @PatriciaG. Have you tried pchisq() instead as I proposed?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for your help! Only I have to turn around "res" and "res.red" in your script example. Aaaaand I actually found the function doing this model comparison stuff for me in the package VGAM. It's called `lrtest()` - I consider this problem to be solved. @jeypeu you helped me finding the right track - thank you!